# asp.net C# webform show report without reportviewer

Tags: asp.net, webforms, report

currently i want to generate the report without showing in reportviewer. I search for the solution online but i only can find the MVC approach. I cant convert it to normal webform behavior.

```
 public ActionResult Report(string id)
        {
            LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Report"), "ReportStateArea.rdlc");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                lr.ReportPath = path;
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
            List<StateArea> cm = new List<StateArea>();
            using (PopulationEntities dc = new PopulationEntities())
            {
                cm = dc.StateAreas.ToList();
            }
            ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("MyDataset", cm);
            lr.DataSources.Add(rd);
            string reportType = id;
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string fileNameExtension;



            string deviceInfo =

            "<DeviceInfo>" +
            "  <OutputFormat>" + id + "</OutputFormat>" +
            "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
            "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
            "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
            "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
            "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
            "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
            "</DeviceInfo>";

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;
            byte[] renderedBytes;

            renderedBytes = lr.Render(
                reportType,
                deviceInfo,
                out mimeType,
                out encoding,
                out fileNameExtension,
                out streams,
                out warnings);


            return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
        }
    enter code here
```

Here is the sample of code that can allow user to generate the report in different format such as PDF, excel, image. ( http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2013/09/microsoft-report-in-mvc-4.html ).

Anyone can help or provide me a website which have a simple tutorial of that by using the `SQL` select statement instead of `LINQ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as returning the report from a WebForms page, what you have above is actually pretty close. You want to return the *renderedBytes* array through the *Response* object of your current *Page* context like:

```
protected void ReportPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string id = "PDF"; // get this from another control on your page
    LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Report"), "ReportStateArea.rdlc");
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            lr.ReportPath = path;
        }
    else
        {
            // handle error condition
        }

    List<StateArea> cm = new List<StateArea>();
    using (PopulationEntities dc = new PopulationEntities())
        {
            cm = dc.StateAreas.ToList();
        }
    ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("MyDataset", cm);
    lr.DataSources.Add(rd);
    string reportType = id;
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string fileNameExtension;

    string deviceInfo =

    "<DeviceInfo>" +
    "  <OutputFormat>" + id + "</OutputFormat>" +
    "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
    "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
    "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
    "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
    "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
    "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
    "</DeviceInfo>";

    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streams;
    byte[] renderedBytes;

    renderedBytes = lr.Render(
        reportType,
        deviceInfo,
        out mimeType,
        out encoding,
        out fileNameExtension,
        out streams,
        out warnings);


    Response.Clear(); // we're going to override the default page response
    Response.ContentType = mimeType;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report." + fileNameExtension);
    Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes);
    Response.End();
    }
```

This will replace the normal page response with your report content.

As far as SQL vs Linq, the DataSource object that ReportViewer uses is the old-style System.Data.DataTable so just look for information on populating a DataTable from SQL.

Comment: HI, thankz for your code but the last line CompleteRequest() appear error during design time. The error is do not exist in the context.

Comment: Try using Response.End() instead (see edited example)

Comment: Hi, it work!!!thankz!!! Furthermore is it possible to make a save file dialog if choose Image/Word/Excel file type? Because I realize that if i choose these file format, it will download to the pc but i wish can allow user to enter the file name and file path to save.

Comment: see latest edit of my example - specifically the additional header for "content-disposition" right before the BinaryWrite. It should force the file save dialog to open allowing the user to change the file name.

Comment: Hi thank for your reply, i tried this before but unfortunately it do not work, it did pop up the save dialog but it doesn't allow to change file name. In addition, it directly download if use Chrome

Comment: It's possible that the MIME mapping on your machine is different than mine. Try setting Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; so your browser's application associations don't try to handle the file directly.